Is "London" is used as emphatic expression?
In Emma (2020), in presence of Mr Elton, the local vicar, Mr Woodhouse commented
on his daughter Emma's potrait of Harriet, a young girl:

Mr Woodhouse: Yes. It is very pretty. When It is finished, you must
have it framed.
Mr Elton: Allow me. Trust me with this commission, Miss Woodhouse, and
I will ride to London the moment I am asked.

Is "London" is used as emphatic expression?

No. London is a city.

No, as @BillyKerr said, London is a city. Mr. Elton is saying that he will help frame the painting when it is finished. I haven't seen this particular film, but I assume based on context that framing the painting will involve someone taking the painting to the city of London to find a professional framer. If this is the case, then Mr. Elton is offering to take it himself to London and arrange for the framing.

In the book the passage is "The next thing wanted was to get the picture framed; and here were a few difficulties. It must be done directly; it must be done in London; the order must go through the hands of some intelligent person whose taste could be depended on; and Isabella, the usual doer of all commissions, must not be applied to, . . ." Presumably that is the reason for the spoken emphasis – the only place that will do is London: not locally.

Please explain why you think this is "emphatic".  What do you think this is emphasising?  Can you give any other example of using the word "London" for emphasis?  Can you give any example of using any word for emphasis? Do you know the usual meaning of "London"? Why do you suppose the usual meaning doesn't apply here?

Do you mean something like  "I'd take it all the way to Timbuktu!"  ?

Yes,  perhaps the question you want to ask is "is 'London' being used as hyperbole" by Mr Elton.   (No, it isn't)  Please edit to clarify

London is a) a place b) the place
Yes, he will literally take it to London to have it framed, but there is an implication that framing in London will be of a higher quality than in a provincial town since the best in their field (all fields, not just portrait framers) will be in London.
